# Heat dissipation in space - how do they do that?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, vacuum, aircraft, cooling

Consider a space aircraft. During its propulsion, I believe a lot of heat is transmitted to the aircraft by simple contact with the motor. But in space, there is no air to cool the aircraft. The only way to remain cool is by radiating infrared to the space. I believe that the corresponding equilibrium temperature is very high, so how do they prevent astronauts and apparatus from frying?

Comment: Maybe the piece you're missing is that the average radiation temperature of space is only a few degrees Kelvin.  Radiation heat transfer is based on the temperature difference to the fourth power, so radiation to space is substantial.  Of course, if you are in low Earth orbit, then almost half of your radiation is with the Earth, not open space.

Comment: I understand. So, in space, anything warm radiate much more energy than on earth, and this will cool it much faster than I thought. This should be the answer.

Comment: Sort of... An object will emit the same amount of radiation energy if in space or on the Earth.  But the amount of energy radiated BACK to it will be much less if in space.  So there will be a NET energy loss in space.  I didn't make it an answer because there's a lot more details to consider such as surface area and surface emissivities.

Comment: Thx again. I think it is not mandatory to write a complete answer. A partial answer is good too.